# What is the meaning of "T.M"?

Tags: communication, project-gemini

In the movie, *First Man (2018)*, Neil Armstrong is getting into Gemini 8 space craft. He overhears capcom voice:

> CARNARVON CAPCOM: Guaymas, read you loud and clear. We have S band
>   track. We have just locked up on **T.M**.

What is the meaning of "T.M"?

Comment: It won't help for Gemini-specific questions, but the annotated [Apollo flight journals](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/) explain a lot of the jargon of the period. You might enjoy them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely **T**ele**m**etry.

https://www.acronymfinder.com/Telemetry-(TM).html

Although usually TLM is used.

The "locking" terminology is explained here
: [What is carrier lock and bit lock?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33257/what-is-carrier-lock-and-bit-lock)